# How to deploy Activiti workflow in Alfresco Community 4.2.C?

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I'm trying to deploy a new workflow in Alfresco Community 4.2.C using Activiti. I found out that the "workflow console" comes only with the Enterprise edition. So, is there anyway to deploy an Activiti workflow in Alfresco Community?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can manually place all the files under 
/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension
It should be picked up by alfresco.

Comment: what files you are talking about? I've found that I need to create the following catalogs: config

    ¦→ classes

             ¦→ alfresco

                      ¦→ extension

                      ¦→ messages

                      ¦→ web-extension    where must be placed the following files: my-activiti-model.xml, my-activiti-context.xml, my-activiti.properties in 1st 2, and edited share-config-custom.xml to the last one. Is that all? Will it be enough?

Comment: maybe there are any msven plugin which will create all the nesessary structure and files?

Comment: You should not place them under alfresco share folder structure it should be deployed at location I have mentioned. Only share-config-custom.xml file will go under "web-extension" and that is for configuring user interface of workflow for alfresco share.

Answer (score 2):

I just started learning workflows myself. I'm following the [Jeff Potts tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-workflow/advanced-workflow-article-2ed.pdf) and this explains how to deploy the workflow in community edition, among other things. More or less what Mitpatoliya answered.

Answer (score 0):

You should make Alfresco bootstrap your activiti configuration file during startup. In order to do so the context file should be places in %ALFRESCO%/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension folder.
[Here](http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc/topics/wf-deploy-taskmodel.html) is everything you need to know about deploying workflow model and workflow definition in Alfresco
Hope it helps.
Also, Jeff Pots tutorial is also a great start, it helped me a lot, too.